# How to block navigation bar/status bar android java

Tags: java, android, statusbar, navigationbar

How to block the navigation bar in android from my app. My app must haven't take the chance go to the settings and other components.

**This code on Kotlin**

I block the action bar by: `window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY) window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`

In the photo it is the red zone, I can to override `back-button` and `home-button` (I make my app as a launcher for android) and I have did this.

But the main problem - is the button of multitasking - green zone.

The overriding method `onUserLeaveHint` not solve my problem.

How to remove this button or hide the navigation bar?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have used below code for hiding the navigation bar & status bar in activity.

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
   if (hasFocus) {  
 view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOU _STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | 
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
       );

   }
}
```

In one of My Custom camera app i have used this which shows the full screen camera view witout notification bar & status bar and when you drag from top or bottom then it will show you. 
Happy Coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this example.
in which shown how to disable :

[Click here][below]

https://github.com/mugku/Android-LockScreenSample-DisableHomeButtonKey

Its tricky part pelase have h deep dive into this.or please check other lock screen example or locker apps. in which screen lock screen has this code.

Comment: Could you please write some piece of code so that if link is broken one can refer from shared code

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(SettingsProvider.loadPreventOverviewButtonMode(this)) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
    }
}
```